# serializing JSON from a form to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to convert form data upon submit to update a json object.

This is what I have so far:

```
var app = {
slidePreviews: "",
selectedTheme: "",
slideDuration: 7000,
    slides: []
};
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#slideForm').on('submit', function(event){
    var slide = $(this).toJSON;
    app.slides.push(slide);
    return false;
});
});
```

```html
<div id="themeOption"></div> 
<div id="ppt"></div>

<pre><code id="presentation"></code></pre>

<form id="slideForm">
<dl>
    <dt><label for="presTitle">Title of the Presentation:</label></dt>
    <dd><input id="presTitle" type="text" name="presentation.title"/></dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt><label for="slideTitle">Slide Title:</label></dt>
    <dd><input id="slideTitle" type="text" name="presentation.slide.title"/></dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt><label for="slideHeader">Slide Header:</label></dt>
    <dd><input id="slideHeader" type="text" name="presentation.slide.header"/></dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt>Content</dt>
    <dd>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="presentation.slide.content">Slide content here</textarea>
    </dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt></dt>
    <dd><input type="submit" value="Send" /></dd>
</dl>
```

I want the object app to be updated with the form data. When I log "slide", I get "undefined". 
Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add parens to your call to `toJSON()` call:

```
var slide = $(this).toJSON();
```

Comment: jQuery has no `toJSON()` method

Comment: My bad.  It's a function in backbone's Model class. http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON

Answer (score 0):

Use the `serialize` function to serialize your form as JSON instead of the `toJSON` function, like this:

```
$(this).serialize();
```

Comment: when I log slides, it returns "function()". I don't seem to get any json

Comment: I don't see a close tag on your `<form>` tag. Is that just a typo?

Comment: If it's printing "function()" when you print `slide` to the console, I'm guessing you forgot the parenthesis on the `serialize()` call, $(this).serialize without parenthesis would return the serialize function instead of calling it. Also, `serialize()` creates a string, you can use `serializeArray()` to get an array of name/value pairs, if you need a JSON object see [this question] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309/1970746).

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `serialize()` like this:

```
var obj = $("#slideForm").serialize();
```